# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process fitting

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes

I am wondering what I am doing wrong with the parameterization of the OU process for day-ahead electricity prices on a weekly resolution. The fitted parameters do not produce satisfying results, as the simulated paths do not look as if they correctly reflect the volatility. For the calculation, I followed the paper by Dixit & Pindyck (1994) and Bastian-Pinto & Brandao (2010). Any tips on what I did wrong?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import datetime

# Calculate log returns
weekly_prices_new['log_prices'] = np.log(weekly_prices_new['Close'])
weekly_prices_new['log_returns'] = weekly_prices_new['log_prices'].diff()
weekly_prices_new.dropna(inplace=True)


delta_t = 1

# Linear regression for log returns with log(P_t-1) as X and log(P_t) - log(P_t-1) as y
X_log_prices = weekly_prices_new['log_prices'].shift(1).values[1:].reshape(-1, 1)
y_log_returns = weekly_prices_new['log_returns'].values[1:].reshape(-1, 1)
reg_log_returns = sm.OLS(y_log_returns, sm.add_constant(X_log_prices)).fit()

# Parameters for log returns
b_log_returns = reg_log_returns.params[1] + 1
a_log_returns = reg_log_returns.params[0]
std_e_log_returns = reg_log_returns.bse[1]

# Calculate OU parameters
eta_log_returns = -np.log(b_log_returns) / delta_t
sigma_log_returns = std_e_log_returns * np.sqrt((2 * np.log(b_log_returns)) / (((b_log_returns**2) - 1) * delta_t))
mu_log_returns = np.exp((a_log_returns/(1-b_log_returns))+(sigma_log_returns**2/(2*eta_log_returns)))

# Simulate the discretized OU process for log returns
N = 52*5

# Get the last date in the historical data
last_date = weekly_prices_new.index[-1]

# Generate a list of dates for the simulated prices
simulated_dates = [last_date + datetime.timedelta(weeks=x) for x in range(1, N+1)]


# Plot historical prices
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
plt.plot(weekly_prices_new.index, weekly_prices_new['Close'], label='Historical Prices', linewidth=2)

num_paths = 10
for i in range(num_paths):
    P = np.zeros(N)
    random_numbers_log_returns = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
    P[0] = weekly_prices_new['Close'].iloc[-1]

    for t in range(1, N):
        P[t] = np.exp(np.log(P[t-1]) * np.exp(-eta_log_returns * delta_t) + \
        (np.log(mu_log_returns) - (sigma_log_returns**2 / 2)) * (1 - np.exp(-eta_log_returns * delta_t)) + \
        sigma_log_returns * np.sqrt((1 - np.exp(-2 * eta_log_returns * delta_t)) / (2 * eta_log_returns)) * random_numbers_log_returns[t])

    plt.plot(simulated_dates, P, label=f'Simulated Path {i+1}' if i < num_paths-1 else f'Simulated Path {i+1}', linestyle='--', alpha=0.6)

plt.title('Simulated and Historical Electricity Prices using Discretized OU Process')
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Prices')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Historical electricity prices and 10 simulated paths]

Additionally, the fit of the regression looks correct and quite similar to the results of Bastian-Pinto & Brandao (2010).
[image: Regression results]

---

**EDIT:**
I tried to implement the process as suggested in the comments and used [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345773/how-the-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process-can-be-considered-as-the-continuous-time-anal) for guidance. Unfortunately, I still receive paths that differ significantly from the historical price behavior.

The parameter estimation is now:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm


# Calculate log prices
weekly_prices_new['log_prices'] = np.log(weekly_prices_new['Close'])

# Drop the first row since it has NaN values for log_returns
weekly_prices_new.dropna(inplace=True)
delta_t = 1

# Linear regression for log(P_t) as X and log(P_t+1) as y
X_log_prices = weekly_prices_new['log_prices'].values[:-1].reshape(-1, 1)
y_log_prices = weekly_prices_new['log_prices'].shift(-1).values[:-1].reshape(-1, 1)
reg = sm.OLS(y_log_prices, sm.add_constant(X_log_prices)).fit()

# Parameters from linear regression
c = reg.params[0]
b = reg.params[1]
std = reg.bse[1]

# Calculate OU-Parameters
theta = -np.log(b) / delta_t
mu = c/(1-np.exp(-theta*delta_t))
sigma = std * np.sqrt((2*theta)/(1-np.exp(-2*theta*delta_t)))
#sigma = std * np.sqrt((2*theta)/(1-b**2))

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ou_process(mu, theta, sigma, delta_t, n_steps, n_paths, initial_log_price):
    log_paths = np.zeros((n_steps + 1, n_paths))
    log_paths[0] = initial_log_price
    
    # Generate random increments
    increments = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(n_steps, n_paths))
    
    # Simulate the log paths
    for t in range(1, n_steps + 1):
        log_paths[t] = log_paths[t - 1] * np.exp(-theta * delta_t) + mu * (1 - np.exp(-theta * delta_t)) + sigma * np.sqrt((1 - np.exp(-2 * theta * delta_t)) / (2 * theta)) * increments[t - 1]
    
    # Convert log prices to normal prices
    paths = np.exp(log_paths)
    
    return paths


# Simulation parameters
n_steps = 52*5
n_paths = 4
initial_log_price = weekly_prices_new['log_prices'].values[-1]

# Simulate OU paths
paths = ou_process(mu, theta, sigma, delta_t, n_steps, n_paths, initial_log_price)
```

Nevertheless, the paths have not really changed.

```py
# Simulation parameters
n_steps = 52*5
n_paths = 4
initial_log_price = weekly_prices_new['log_prices'].values[-1]

# Simulate OU paths
paths = ou_process(mu, theta, sigma, delta_t, n_steps, n_paths, initial_log_price)

import pandas as pd

# Assuming weekly_prices_new has a DatetimeIndex
last_date = weekly_prices_new.index[-1]
date_range = pd.date_range(start=last_date, periods=n_steps+1, inclusive='left', freq='W')

# Create a DataFrame for the simulated paths with the new DateTimeIndex
simulated_paths = pd.DataFrame(paths, index=date_range)

# Plot the historical data and simulated paths
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

# Plot historical data
plt.plot(weekly_prices_new.index, weekly_prices_new['Close'], label='Historical Data', linewidth=2)

# Plot simulated paths
for i in range(n_paths):
    plt.plot(simulated_paths.index, simulated_paths[i], linestyle='--')

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Prices')
plt.title('Historical Data and Simulated OU Paths (Exact Discretization)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: New results]

Comment: Hi Tobolf: Could you explain this line in your code ? I don't understand why that makes sense. Thanks. # Linear regression for log returns with log(P_t-1) as X and log(P_t) - log(P_t-1)

Comment: Also, IIRC, the discretized version of the ornstein-uhlenbeck is an AR(1) so you should be simulating an AR(1). Maybe the papers are using an approach that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Hi mlofton, for the AR(1), they use the the log of the price $log[P_t]=a+b*log[P_{t−1}]+ε_t $ and rearrange this to $log[P_t]-log[P_{t-1}] = a+(b-1)*log[P_{t−1}]+ε_t$.

Comment: Hi: okay. I've never seen prices being regressed against prices ( because they tend to be not-stationary ) which confused me initially but thanks for explanation. I see it more clearly now. Note that not rejecting $b = +1$ in your model is the same as finding a unit root in the process.. Note that You may want to try to model the returns as an OU being using the log prices seems a little odd to me.

Comment: I have tried your suggested approach and edited my previous post. Unfortunately the results are very similar to the first approach.

Comment: I'm not clear on how you know that your approach is not working ? Thanks.

Comment: For example, I was expecting more pronounced fluctuations similar to the historical data.. which is why I suspect that there is still something wrong.

Comment: Note that non-dynamic regression using one dependent variable can only pick up a linear relation so I'm not sure if you should expect that. Are you talking about obtaining something similar to the blue line ?